# Curl_init() not working on RaspberryPi 3 Jessie

Tags: php, curl, raspberry-pi, init, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a chunk of code on my computer which worked perfectly:

```html
  $curl =curl_init();
$urlCurrent = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=lyon&units=metric&APPID=c0670481fea50f735e7d2558dbbc01e7";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $urlCurrent
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

However when I uploaded it to my RPi (on which Apache2, PHP5 including Php_curl are installed) it just wont work !
After looking for a few hours I figures that the problem comes from the curl_init() method. It makes the entire code crash, and all the following lines of codes vanish. Meaning that I can run the webpage everything before curl_init() shows up but then it just stop browsing the next lines. When looking in the webpage source code, the lines that are supposed to be there are not...
Again, the exact same code works on my computer !!

Please help, I am so close to finish a big project (that is cooooool).

Thank you

Comment: any error in `curl_error()`?

Comment: Any errors at all? Have you turned on error reporting and checked your logs?

Comment: Define "crash".  PHP fatal error, Apache segfaults, no result?  Otherwise `curl_error()` is a good suggestion as devpro said.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it. Eventhough I do not understand what went wrong, by re-installing the disk img of RasPi and starting all over again it worked.
Sorry for those who encounter that problem, but it is the only solution that worked for me.

ByeBye and thanks for your help anyway,
by the way I finished my project and its awesome ! (its a MagicMirror for those who know).